# detection and communication between 2 ios devices

Tags: ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon

I would like to create a very simple app. When 2 peoples (who got the app) are geographically very close (20-30-40 meters), the 2 automatically receive a push notification with some infos about the other person. First, is it technically possible ? What would the most efficient way to make it ? Ibeacons ? Bluetooth ?

Comment: Too far for bluetooth

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do something like what you are describing, however you can't solve it with iBeacon alone, that would just be a single component in the system.

The main parts of the system would be

- Mobile app
- Physical iBeacons (to let you know when you are close by)
- Backend web service (to coordinate between the app)

When a user with your App comes within range of an iBeacon you could have it call up to the web service and provide the iBeacon identifiers. Then you could use that information on the back end to see if another device was also recently with in range. If so, push out a notification.

Just be conservative on your expectations. This would require a number of moving parts, and you should become familiar with the limitations of how iOS background notifications and how iBeacons work.

Comment: One key limitation with an iBeacon solution would be getting this to work in the background on both phones.  iBeacons cannot transmit in the background, so that leaves you with CoreBluetooth.  You would need to make the app advertise its service in the background and have the other app wake up in the background if it sees this service.  See details on how these background modes work here:  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/CoreBluetoothBackgroundProcessingForIOSApps/PerformingTasksWhileYourAppIsInTheBackground.html